# I want to search a specific string form a particular column(contains Strings) in my parse table in android

Tags: android, parse-platform

[I want to search a specific string "f2b5e2511827bc26a1b43d73fa76dc5a0a34daa8" from "manual_friendID" column in my parse table named as "Manual_FriendList"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJh1V.png)

Comment: it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: You are telling or asking...because I can not see you have tried something by yourself.. please refer to [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ParseQuery to look for data. Initialzie it with the class name, then add custom conditions on the required data, in our case search for column 'manual_fiendID' to be equal to your id and then async find your data.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Manual_FriendList");
query.whereEqualTo("manual_frienID", the_id_you_want_to_search);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects,
            ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            //Success - do whatever you want with this user

        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: #galvan this code is not working i have tried this one

Comment: Error 'done(List<ParseObject>,ParseException)' in Anonymous class derived from com.FindCallBack' clashes with 'done(List<T>,ParseException )' in 'com.parse.FindCallBack';both methods have same erasure yet neither overrides the other'

Comment: try it now, I made a minor change, don't forget to replace 'the_id_you_want_to_search" with your firendID

Comment: #galvan Thank you very much.This code is working for me :) you made my day :) Thank you :)